# How to export a variable out of block that relates a pipeline?

Tags: dos

I got a value from pipeline to a variable dd1.

But i can not export a variable out of block.

How to export a variable out of block that relates a pipeline ?

**Example batch script :**

> @echo off
>
> (date /t) | (set /p zDate=& call set zDate=%%zDate:~0,4%% & call echo
>   Possible: %%zDate%% )
>
> echo ImPossible: %zDate%
>
> pause >nul
>
> exit 0

```
Result :
-------------------------------------------

Possible: 2015
ImPossible:
```

Why not export a variable zDate out of Block ?

please answer to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well once a variable within a pipe block is ended, the environment changes to the default file and the variable is lost. The only workaround I can think of is to export the variable into a temp file which is read by the default batch after the pipe ends. Perhaps:

```
@echo off

(date /t) | (set /p zDate=& call set zDate=%%zDate:~0,4%% & call echo Possible: %%zDate%% & call echo %%zDate%%^>%temp%\zDate.txt )

set /p zDate=<%temp%\zDate.txt
echo Impossible: %zDate%

pause >nul

exit 0
```

Is what you intended? If not please let me know and I'll update the answer!

_Arescet